# Writing to JTextArea with CachedThreadPool

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, thread-safety

I asked this in CodeReview but it was closed.

For a school assignment I have to create 54 threads that run simultaneously from a `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` that write to a `JTextArea` in a thread safe manner. Each thread has to write 'A' through 'Z' to the field 1000 times. I've been having issues making the program thread safe no matter where I put the `synchronized` keyword. I have a runnable class that does the writing but I'm having issues keeping it thread safe. The only method I tried that works somewhat is putting a `Thread.sleep(500)` in the loop that cycles through all the letters, which doesn't work when I increase the iterations and is giving a warning in Netbeans anyway.

Will putting the `synchronized` keyword in the correct place make in thread safe or will I have to change the thread itself? I'd left some of my previous attempts in the comments below.

I changed the code so that it works once. It runs one instance that writes to the `JTextArea` but I'm having issues turning this into multiple synchronized threads.

AlphabetThread.java

```
package threadpool;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class AlphabetThread implements Runnable{

    char letter;
    JTextArea toEdit;
    //final int NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS = 1000;

    public AlphabetThread(char e, JTextArea tf) {
        letter = e;
        toEdit = tf;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS; i++) {

            toEdit.setText(toEdit.getText() + letter);

    }

//    public synchronized void createThread() {
//        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS; i++) {
//
//            toEdit.setText(toEdit.getText() + letter);
//        }
//    }
}
```

ThreadPool.java

```
package threadpool;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class ThreadPool {

//    static char letter;
//
//    Thread alphabetThread = new Thread(() -> {
//        char e = letter;
//        mainWindow.textBox.setText(mainWindow.textBox.getText() + e);
//    });
//    public static synchronized AlphabetThread createThread(char e, JTextArea tf) throws InterruptedException {
//        AlphabetThread runMe = new AlphabetThread(e, tf);
//        return runMe;
//    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TextWindow mainWindow = new TextWindow();
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        for (char alphabet = 'A'; alphabet <= 'Z'; alphabet++) {

            AlphabetThread alphabetThread = new AlphabetThread(alphabet, mainWindow.textBox);
            alphabetThread.run();

        }
        pool.shutdown();
    }
}
```

TextWindow.java

```
package threadpool;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class TextWindow extends JFrame {

    public JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    public JTextArea textBox = new JTextArea();

    public TextWindow() throws HeadlessException {

        add(mainPanel);
        textBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450,450));
        textBox.setVisible(true);
        mainPanel.add(textBox);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        pack();
    }

}
```

A full solution is not necessary (though it would be nice). I would prefer some pointers on where to correct the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code. Firstly, the general rule is that you need to synchronize using the *same* monitor object for all the threads. Also your attempts seem to be at synchronizing creating the threads, rather than when doing the writing to the text area. *If swing was thread safe*, you could use the text area as the monitor object, for example:

```
synchronized (toEdit) {
    toEdit.setText(toEdit.getText() + letter);
}
```

And that would be enough to synchronize the writes. However, **swing is not thread safe.** That is the second issue. Modifying `JComponents` must be done only in the event dispatch thread. This is done using [invokeLater()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) or (rarely)`invokeAndWait()`:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        toEdit.setText(toEdit.getText() + letter);
    }
}
```

This also means that all the write requests are queued, and you won't need to worry more about thread safety of the writing part.